# Извлечь из большого файла по многострочному паттерну (sed/grep/perl/awk)

Tags: linux, perl, sed, grep, awk

Есть большой лог-файл (>10гб), в котором, помимо всего прочего, пишутся sip-логи, формата:

```
... другие логи ...

<--- SIP read from UDP:10.10.143.143:7000 --->
INVITE sip:1234@10.10.143.143 SIP/2.0
From: ...
... N-строк ...
Call-ID: 55555-33333-ID-asdf@10.10.143.143
... M-строк ...
<------------->

... другие логи ...

<--- SIP read from UDP:10.10.143.143:7000 --->
BYE sip:1234@10.10.143.143 SIP/2.0
From: ...
... L-строк ...
Call-ID: 55555-33333-ID-asdf@10.10.143.143
... K-строк ...
<------------->

... другие логи ...
```

И задача состоит в том, чтобы вытащить в отдельный файл все sip сообщения по определенному ID, т.е. для `55555-33333-ID-asdf`, из примера выше, получить файл:

```
<--- SIP read from UDP:10.10.143.143:7000 --->
INVITE sip:1234@10.10.143.143 SIP/2.0
From: ...
...
Call-ID: 55555-33333-ID-asdf@10.10.143.143
...
<------------->
<--- SIP read from UDP:10.10.143.143:7000 --->
ACK sip:1234@10.10.143.143 SIP/2.0
From: ...
...
Call-ID: 55555-33333-ID-asdf@10.10.143.143
...
<------------->

...

<--- SIP read from UDP:10.10.143.143:7000 --->
BYE sip:1234@10.10.143.143 SIP/2.0
From: ...
...
Call-ID: 55555-33333-ID-asdf@10.10.143.143
...
<------------->
```

Каким образом это можно получить? Смотрел в сторону sed, но не смог разобраться, как найдя строку с паттерном cодержащим ID `Call-ID: 55555-33333-ID-asdf@10.10.143.143` добавить в пространство шаблона строки до паттерна:

```
<--- SIP read from UDP:10.10.143.143:7000 --->
INVITE sip:1234@10.10.143.143 SIP/2.0
From: ...
...
```

Если пространство шаблона начинать с `<--- SIP read from UDP:10.10.143.143:7000 --->` и добавлять в него строки, то не будет ли это через чур затратно? в логе больше миллиона таких sip-сообщений, из которых с нужным ID - 3-5шт. (имхо по этому логичней сначала найти паттерн с ID и плясать от этого)

Пробовал grep, но есть проблема, что длина sip-сообщений разная, и можно ориентироваться только на то, что он начинается с `<--- SIP read from UDP:10.10.143.143:7000 --->` и заканчивается `<------------->`

С perl не смог разобраться, и не знаю как он с большими файлами, дружит? Поделитесь опытом.
Может у кого-то есть решение?

Comment: Пробовали [решение в лоб](https://regex101.com/r/JFEsR6/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> можно ориентироваться только на то, что он начинается с `<--- SIP read from UDP:10.10.143.143:7000 --->` и заканчивается `<------------->`
>
> содержащим `ID Call-ID: 55555-33333-ID-asdf@10.10.143.143`

```
X="<--- SIP read from UDP:10.10.143.143:7000 --->"
Y="Call-ID: 55555-33333-ID-asdf@10.10.143.143"
Z="<------------->"

awk "/$X/,/$Z/" file.log | awk "BEGIN{RS=ORS=\"$Z\"}/$Y/"
```